# Why am i getting a segmentation fault with this code? This code is barely running so there's probably an error in the constructor or copy constructor

Tags: c++

I keep getting a segmentation fault with this code. I cant understand why. Is there some glaring error in the constructors/destructor or is there a problem with the way i am using the pointers?

```
template <class T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList()
{
 head=NULL;
}
```

COPY CONSTRUCTOR

```
template <class T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList(const LinkedList<T>& otherLinkedList)
{
                        head= new ListItem<T> (NULL);
                        ListItem<T>* temp;
                        ListItem<T>* writeto;
                        temp=otherLinkedList.getHead();
                        writeto=head;
                        while (temp->next != NULL)
                                {
                                writeto->value=temp->value;
                                temp=temp->next;
                                writeto=writeto->next;
                                writeto= new ListItem<T> (NULL);
                                }
                        writeto=NULL;
                        ListItem<T>* pre;
                        pre=writeto;
                        while (pre->prev != head)
                                {
                                pre=pre->prev;
                                writeto->prev=pre;              /
                                }


}
```

DESTRUCTOR

```
template <class T>
LinkedList<T>::~LinkedList()
{
ListItem <T> *temp;
                temp=head;
                while (temp->next != NULL)
                        {
                        temp=temp->next;
                        delete temp->prev;
                        }
                delete temp;
                delete head;

}
```

INSERTS NEW NODE AT HEAD OF THE LINKED LIST

```
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::insertAtHead(T item)
{
    ListItem <T> *newnode= new ListItem <T>(item);
                if(head==NULL)
                {
                head=newnode;newnode->next=NULL;
                }
                {
                newnode->next=head;
                head->prev=newnode;
                head=newnode;
                }



}
// INSERTS NEW NODE AT TAIL OF LIST
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::insertAtTail(T item)
{
 ListItem <T> *newnode;
 newnode = new ListItem <T> (item);
                //newnode->value=item;
                if(head==NULL)
                {
                head=newnode;
                newnode->next=NULL;
                }
                {
                ListItem <T> *here=head;
                while (here->next != NULL)
                {
                        here=here->next;
                }
                here->next= newnode;
                newnode->prev=here;
                newnode->next=NULL;             
                }
}
```

Comment: No way to help you unless you post the client code (i.e. the code where you call the functions of the given class) and the exact line where it crashes. Code can't "barely run", it either runs or doesn't.

Comment: Without seeing your `main`, it's impossible to say for sure, but my guess is that you are using `prev` without setting it.

Comment: Would the upvoter mind to explain how this question contains a [MCVE] please?

Comment: missing `else` at `insertAtHead` method and `insertAtTail` method

Comment: Please indent your code so that it's readable.

Comment: You do not have an assignment operator, or you didn't post it.

Comment: I should add that seg-faults are typically really easy to debug. Just run up the code in the debugger and walk up the stack to figure out where in your code the fault started. I _much_ prefer seg faults and asserts to "Hmm, why is the result 46, it's meant to be 42?" in a large application.

Comment: What does the debugger say?

Comment: The destructor deletes `head` twice

Comment: `writeto=writeto->next; writeto= new ListItem<T> (NULL);` is a mistake. You access a null or uninitialized pointer. It should be `writeto->next = new ListItem<T>(NULL); writeto = writeto->next;`

Comment: `writeto =  NULL;  pre = writeto; pre->prev` dereferences a null pointer

Comment: Using a debugger would have shown up the errors in my last two comments. To avoid this sort of situation arising, write less code in one go, and test it before moving onto the next task.

Comment: Thanks. This helped a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `if/else` properly.

when you write:

```
if(head==NULL)
 {
    head=newnode;newnode->next=NULL;
 }
 {
   newnode->next=head;
   head->prev=newnode;
   head=newnode;
 }
```

both blocks will be activated in case `head == NULL`.

You should use else, like this:

```
if(head==NULL)
 {
    head=newnode;newnode->next=NULL;
 }
 else
 {
   newnode->next=head;
   head->prev=newnode;
   head=newnode;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to programming so I frequently make syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

1. In your copy constructor, what if `otherLinkedList.getHead()` returns `NULL`? This will set `temp` as `NULL` and dereferncing `NULL` will be undefined behavior. This means you have just created an empty linked list and trying to copy from it.
2. Another possibility is that in the destructor, if either the list is empty or list has just one element, the `delete head` will try to delete the object 2 times and this could cause the error

Comment: I made both of the changes you suggested. Half of my code is running with the test file now :) thanks !!

Comment: That's good to know. Can you please give me some credit points for this:-)?